# Codeigniter 2.x cron issues

Tags: codeigniter, https, cron

I need to setup cron jobs on a codeigniter site on a shared host that uses cpanel. The cron script works when run via a browser, however, I first tried running it in cron using curl and then wget, but neither of these worked. Ultimately I will want to run the jobs via php/cli.

As for why the curl and wget methods don't work, could it have anything to do with the fact that the site is completely SSL, and htaccess is used to rewrite all http requests to https? To be honest, I haven't actually ruled out the fact that the host may have disabled cron for some strange reason.

EDIT: Have checked with the host and cron is running fine!

I read an [article](http://stevethomas.com.au/php/how-to-run-cron-jobs-in-codeigniter.html) here about cron and CI CLI and it gives this example;

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/clinic/public_html/index.php cron foo
```

I have tried that method but my controler is inside a subdirectory eg /controlers/utility/cron.php and I have CI setup to not use the index.php So how would I run cron in this way?

Comment: What do you mean "I have CI setup to not use the index.php"? You mean it's not present in the url?

Comment: @complex857 I mean config is set to not use index.php in URL's and have mod rewrite setup in htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subdirectories in you parameters of index.php like this to reach the controller and method you want:

```
php index.php utility/cron method_in_controller
```

Comment: That's what I thought, and I tried that. My host looked at the cron logs and found these errors; Message: Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR; Filename: core/Input.php; Line Number: 351; Not sure what that means. Also the script will not run under cron using curl. Yet the script works fine when run via browser.

Comment: This error seems to be a codeigniter bug (or at least a non checked error condition) in the current stable. You could try get a backtrace and simply not requesting ip address when you are coming from a cli request. However, if you got an error that means that some code is running. This curl vs browser thing is suspicious to me, maybe that is not a php level error. Try setting the `uri_protocol` config value to `auto` in the `app/config/config.php`.

Comment: Another cron job (same cPanel account) on another CI developed site under curl http is working fine. It must be something to do with https.

Comment: I'm at this point uncertain what's happening. The above way of giving the parameters works in my environment. I'm afraid there's nothing to else to do but to debug. You could try to bump the `log_threshold` to `4` that will give you overwhelming amount of tracing info during CI boostrap, maybe that helps.

Comment: I have made a simple curl script that I can access through the browser that will mimic the cron job using curl. I am getting no return from that with `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` returning 0. Thanks for your help complex857. I will continue debugging.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is really very embarrassing. Despite checking the script several times and confirming it worked when run in a browser, I overlooked the fact that an authentication function had inadvertently been pasted in, and as I was logged in in the browser I was able to execute the cron script, but that's why it was failing when cron tried to run it. Sorry for wasting your time complex857, and thanks very much for your help any way!